# BaseUrl не использует полный путь. вырезая часть до .com

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, playwright

Пишу автотесты на Playwright, появилась необходимость запускать тесты либо на продакшине, либо на дев сайде, решил реализовать запуск следующим образом, в playwright.config.ts имею следующее:

```
projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',

      /* Project-specific settings. */
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        viewport: {width:1920, height: 1080},
        baseURL: process.env.STAGING === '1' ? 'https://neo.cultbooking.com/CPC/?agentcode=58078&hotelcode=60114' : 'https://dev.cultbooking.com/CPC/?agentcode=58078&hotelcode=60114',
      },
    },
  ],
```

где, как видно, в зависимости от аргумента Staging будет совершаться навигация либо туда либо туда, проблема в следующем, к примеру совершается переход по первой ссылке, (пытаюсь выяснить почему) она обрезается и переходит на https://neo.cultbooking.com, что мне никак не подходит, как решить данную проблему ?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать обратный слеш в первой строке для Staging. Ссылка со слешом в конце не работает в браузере, а без слеша работает

Comment: @AndreiKhotko да, это косяк с моей стороны, я уже просто тестировал различные вариации, дуамл может слеши поменять или еще что, ничего не помогло, правильная ссылка без слеша в конце, работает нормально, но все равно не считывается полный путь

Comment: Зачем вам нужен такой специфичный путь? baseURL - это путь, по которому любой автотест сможет строить относительные пути

Comment: @AndreiKhotko данный путь является необходимым, потому что тестировать нужно определенный функционал с определенными параметрами (которые в ссылке и указаны), методом кликов с условного www.url.com перейти на именно этот не получится